How to Debug C# .NET Code: Step-by-Step Guide
If I want to step into the C# code of .NET MAUI during debugging to see how it works, I encounter : when I press F11, it doesn't allow me to step through the MAUI framework code. Instead, it just skips over it.
Here are some visual examples:


For instance, when debugging my own code, the debugger steps through line by line as expected. However, when it reaches a point where it should enter the MAUI code, the debugger simply bypasses it, making it impossible to inspect the inner workings of the framework.

Try this: Check Tools | Options | Debugging | General and disable "Enable Just My Code" it it's enabled.

The chances are that the code being called has the DebuggerStepThrough attribute set and you'll need to disable Just My Code in VS

In the screenshot you provided, you set a breakpoint in the Announce method of the SemanticScreenReader class. This class belongs to the Maui native framework and is the original code of Maui, so it cannot be debugged through breakpoints.
However, when your project uses it, you can set breakpoints in the relevant code, which can trigger breakpoints normally.
For example, in the OnCounterClicked event of the MainPage.xaml.cs of the default project.
SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);


Also, I tried going into the native code by setting breakpoints on the windows platform, and again, it doesn't work. This may be a visual studio platform issue!
